# Using audio SSML tag causes Alexa to respond with verbal error

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, ssml

Using the audio SSML tag with Alexa causes it to speak the verbal error:

> the uri scheme for the requested audio resource is not valid

Answer (score 1):

The SRC attribute should point to a valid audio file accessible via an SSL based URI. Thus using an **HTTPS**, not an HTTP based request. Therefore if your audio resources are stored on an S3 instance, the REST API method should be used in order to make the request for your audio resources.